# Не открывается форма регистрации в Spring Boot приложении в Heroku

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, heroku

Проблема:
Не открывается форма регистрации в приложении Spring Boot + Spring Security на heroku.

На локальной машине все ок.

В чём проблема понять не могу:

Вот основной код:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan("com.github.owgrant24.springbootone")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    // Правила (ограничения прав)
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            // Указываем URL которые будут доступны только анонимным (неавторизованным) пользователям
            .antMatchers("/sign_up", "/login").anonymous()
            // Указываем URL которые будут доступны только авторизованным пользователям
            .antMatchers("/cars/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/static/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            // Указываем где у нас форма логина
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login/process")
            // задаем что будет будет в качестве username
            .usernameParameter("email")
            // задаем что будет будет в качестве password в форме (по умолчанию - password)
            .passwordParameter("password")
            // При неудачной авторизации сюда будет редирект
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            // Когда пользователь прошёл аутентификацию и хочет зайти на странички для не авторизированных
            // пользователей
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/cars")
            .and()
            // добавлена возможность logout
            .logout();
}

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Вот контроллер, который отвечает за авторизацию и аутентификацию

```
@Controller
public class AuthController {
    private UserService userService;
    private UserValidator userValidator;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserValidator(UserValidator userValidator) {
        this.userValidator = userValidator;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "redirect:/cars";
    }

    @GetMapping("/sign_up")
    public String getSignUp(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "/auth/sign_up";
    }

    @PostMapping("/sign_up")
    public String signUp(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
        userValidator.validate(user, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "/auth/sign_up";
        }
        userService.saveUser(user);
        return "redirect:/login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "auth/sign_in";
    }

}
```

Вот ссылка на мой проект, вдруг я не все указал, может проблема не в этом...
https://github.com/owgrant24/ExampleProject/tree/master/SpringBootOne

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка закралась тут :

```
@GetMapping("/sign_up")
public String getSignUp(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "auth/sign_up";
}

@PostMapping("/sign_up")
public String signUp(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
    userValidator.validate(user, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "auth/sign_up";
    }
    userService.saveUser(user);
    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

было

```
return "/auth/sign_up";
```

стало

```
return "auth/sign_up";
```